# my windows 10 does not open immediately instead it keeps hibernating

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

I dont know why it is happening to my 'upgraded' windows 7 to windows 10. I could open it but it says on the screen,"hibernating"... it keeps loading that I almost feel sick and it is still not done. help me please

Answer (score 0):

When you log off or put the computer to sleep and then try logging in again it just shows “Hibernating” and you are unable to get into the login screen to login to your laptop. You could try the methods below to check.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/laptop-stuck-on-the-screen-showing-hibernating/d4dd2c0c-69db-47e8-80ec-e230f54d5aaf

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.